# Translating Website

Tags: plugins, plugin-qtranslate

How to translate my website into another language like ***Malayalam***. Can You suggest something. There is a problem when I used GTranslate plugin, that is it doesn't translate correctly. There is any chance of content editing/ changing the content when translating a page?

Answer (score 0):

**Polylang**
This plugin will help you. 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/

Answer (score 0):

You can translate your website with [WPML](https://wpml.org/). It is a paid plugin. However, it’s by far the most comprehensive option. More than 400,000 websites are using it. Follow these steps:

1. Install and activate the plugin.
2. Click on **WPML** in your WordPress menu.
3. The plugin will automatically detect your WordPress site’s language.
   Click on the **Next** button.
4. Choose your desired language that you want to enable on your site.
5. Add the language switcher.
6. Click on **Generate a key for this site** button. It will take you
   to WPML website. Here, you will have to add your site. Once added,
   click on it to get the site key. Copy and paste it into your
   WordPress site.
7. Finally, click on the **Finish** button.